# Wordpress how to create grouping like category

Tags: plugins

**Wordpress how to create grouping like category**

As my wordpress site is writing reviews on Television shows, and they have actors and actress.

I would like to create a grouping that goes by the actor/actress name.

Lets say "Actor Andrew act in TV Superman and TV Spiderman while Actor Milley act in TV Superman and TV Batman"

I want link Andrew to Television show "Superman & Spiderman" while Superman itself is a category and Spiderman itself is a category because the posts in

Superman like Superman Episode 1, 2 and so on..

Then we post pictures, word and summary per episode.

How do I actually create an additional grouping in wordpress that I can contain the actor/actress name and bind it to category(The Television show)

Comment: It is called a [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) and you can start by reading about it in the Codex.

Comment: @helgatheviking 
 
I wanna categorize my category, but I don't want create the actor/actress in Category. is it possible to do it elsewhere?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please read about taxonomies (via the Codex and the wpbeginner link below) and try to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use tags or categories to create these groupings. Here is an article on it that should be useful to you. http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/categories-vs-tags-seo-best-practices-which-one-is-better/

Comment: I wanna categorize my category, but I don't want create the actor/actress in Category. is it possible to do it elsewhere?